# Stickies - how to place a sticky on top of a fullscreen desktop (multiple desktops)

Tags: display, desktop, stickies

I use full screen desktops a lot (ctrl + cmd + f) / (ctrl + up).

Is it possible to put a sticky on top of a desktop which has an app open full screen?

What I really want is regardless of whichever desktop I'm in and whichever page I go to, the sticky should remain in the same place on the screen.  This would then mean I don't lose track of my very important sticky note.

Comment: 'Fullscreeen' is exclusive to one app. You could do it if you use 'maximise' instead.

Comment: @Tetsujin and do you think there is a way to keep the app on the screen in the same place regardless of which desktop I have open?

Comment: Yes, from the Dock, right-click>options>All Desktops. That will follow you around, so long as you don't use fullscreen. Set any sticky to Float on Top & it will always be in front.

Comment: @Tetsujin you mean right click the app and select options>All Desktops, I don't have that option (just keep in dock, open at login, show in finder)

Comment: Maybe you only have one Space [Desktop] set up? Fullscreens don't count as Spaces

Comment: Yes! that was the one, thank you so much

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works for me on Big Sur (yes, both "all desktops" from the dock and "float on top" from the stickies window menu are selected, but it won't show up on a full screen Mail.app desktop). Probably another one of the many UI regressions for (perceived) niche apps or corner cases that are just so annoying in their totality...

Comment: See also https://old.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/w5djxi/floating_notes_over_full_screen_app_macos_monterey/ which mentions [old Evernote MacOS client](https://web.archive.org/web/20220502204456mp_/https://cdn1.evernote.com/mac-smd/public/EvernoteLegacy_RELEASE_7.14.1_458325.zip) as having this functionality ([via](https://discussion.evernote.com/forums/topic/145540-evernote-legacy/)).